# Should I be concerned about message size when publishing events?

Tags: c#

We are using the [CAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_UI_Application_Block) Event System for messaging across our application. We have a case where we publish a message to open a file, and pass along an `OpenFileArgs` object containing data about the file, such as id, file name, extension, etc. This object does **not** include in the actual byte array of data for the file.

Our code that receives these messages uses the data to obtain the actual file bytes from the database, and does something with it (Save, Open, etc).

I am considering including the actual file byte array in the data object we publish so we don't need to make a second call to the database to obtain it. The only concern I can think of with this is it may increase the size of the data object used by the CAB Event System.

Is the size of the objects published using the CAB Event System (or something similar since I know CAB is effectively dead) something I should be concerned about? I have tried looking around for best practices regarding this, but my Google-Fu is failing me today.

Comment: default comment on performance questions: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ (just for inspiration, no offence)

Comment: @RenéVogt Thanks, I am aware of that and tend to agree with it, but think since this is a much broader question about best practices with message sizes when working with event publishing systems, it would be something that the community may have the answer to :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on a few factors:

1. Memory consumption - is the message going to persist for any amount of time, either intentionally (the message is stored until delivered) or indirectly (the message is stored in something which lazily de-references contents inside of the event bus, like a `ConcurrentDictionary` for example)? You'd need to examine the source of the messaging system to be sure, along with probably taking memory utilization traces.
2. Memory pressure and GC impact - is the allocation of the byte array going to cause memory pressure that results in a collection and inadvertent promotion of unrelated transient objects to gen 2 (ultimately resulting in more gen 2 GC's)? This is a worry no matter where you allocate the byte arrays, but much more significant if the messages keep those byte arrays rooted longer than they otherwise would be.
3. Messaging Performance - is the messaging system performing some kind of serialization that would be slower for large messages? Usually only applies to inter-process or inter-machine messaging, doesn't really apply to something like CAB.

For CAB I'd think only #1 and #2 apply- if the byte arrays are significantly large, you may want to consider passing a reference to a stream, a file handle, etc. The idea is that you don't want to inadvertently keep those bytes on the heap for any significant amount of time (if at all). Another approach is pre-allocating a large byte buffer (or a pool of them) ahead of time and re-using it if possible to avoid allocating new ones with each message.